# Unity3d moving object along complex curv

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am using unity3d what is easiest way to animate moving object along
complex curve (points of curve is not static (dynamic points))?

Comment: I have not yet used them but [AnimationCurve](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) and  [AnimationClip.SetCurve](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SetCurve.html)  sounds promising

Answer (score 2):

Kay is correct - for "ultimate control" you could build an AnimationClip with your own AnimationCurves within. There is a sample of setting values into an AnimationCurve under the Unity Docs [AnimationCurve.keys](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve-keys.html).

But that might be a bit low level - you can also use a tweening library such as iTween or HOTween which will accept an array of Vector3, durations, easing types, etc. and allow you to playback motions along these curves.

iTween example and plugins: http://pixelplacement.com/2010/12/03/visual-editor-for-itween-motion-paths/
HOTween example: http://www.holoville.com/hotween/examples.html

Comment: I inserted the link - can please check if it is the right one? My +1 should give you access to images and links :-)

Comment: Nice! - yes that is the link I was trying to insert - showing moving an object along a pre-calculated curve. Thanks for the bump! I should have also pointed out that each curve is for one dimension, the poster would need two or three curves to move along a reasonable path.